# error: The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got ndim=2

Tags: python, python-3.x, ode, differential-equations, odeint

I'm trying to solve a simple ODE in python with odeint, but the output is always that i have more dimensions in the input array. I have looked up and i don't see the problem

[Error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CMUV.png)

The blue one, is the equation i want to solve
[ode i want to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiQQf.png)

And this is my code

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y0 = [1]
th = np.linspace(-180,180)

def pend(y,th):
    r=10
    a = 5; # Weibe efficiency factor
    n = 3; # Weibe form factor
    ths = -20; # start of combustion  º
    thd = 60; # duration of combustion º 
    gamma = 1.4
    q = 34.8
    #state variables
    P = y
    
    #define volume 
    vol = (1 + (r-1)/2*(1 - np.cos(th*np.pi/180)))/r
    dvol = (r-1)/2*np.sin(th*np.pi/180)/r
    
    #definimos para la fracción de masa
    dum =(th-ths)/thd; 
    if th > ths:
        temp = -a*dum**n
        x= 1 -np.exp(temp)
        dx =n*a*(1-x)*dum**(n-1) 
    else:
        dx = 0
    
    dP = -gamma*P/vol*dvol + (gamma - 1)*q/vol*dx
    
    #vector con las primeras derivadas de las variables de estado
    dydth = [dP]
    return dydth

sol = odeint(pend, y0, th)
plt.close()
plt.plot(th, sol[:, 0], 'b')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

If anyone wants to help me I would be soooo grateful

Answer (score 0):

You never unpack the input array, like `P=y[0]`. Thus all calculations with `P` are done as array operations, `dP` at the end is an array. As you pack it again as array, you get an array of dimension 2.

However, this only applies to the first branch, in the second branch `dx=0` is just a scalar. But upgrading a scalar to a simple array is done automatically by the odeint interface, so that should not provide an error

Answer (score 0):

When you define dydth with the brackets its changes the ndim to 2

swap to return (dP), or have dydth = (dP) then return dydth